# Which files does macOS source when logging in and starting a new Terminal session?

Tags: macos

As the title states. Which files does macOS source?

In Ubuntu it's at login `~/.profile`, and for a new terminal session `~/.bashrc`. I'd like to know the macOS equivalent.

Comment: I believe you can choose your default shell ([see this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/453236)). The answer depends on your shell because it's the shell that sources files, not OS *per se*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no shell is necessarily involved when you log into the macOS GUI, so no shell scripts get sourced at GUI login time. If you have stuff you want to run at GUI login time, add them to your login items in `System Preferences > Users & Groups`, or create a launchd plist in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Answer (score 0):

At login the loginwindow.app sets up a basic environment available to all applications. When you start a terminal session the Terminal.app calls `login`, so the shell is treated as a login shell. `Bash` would then read `/private/etc/profile` and either `~/.bash_profile`,`~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` in that order and execute commands from the first one found that exists and is readable. None of these files exist in your home folder unless you create them.